# ASP MVC Binding Variable number of dropDownLists

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I need to bind a variable number of dropdownlists, how do I achieve this?

In my project, until now I have only had to deal with binding to a known number of dropdown lists. To do this I have simply done the below:

viewModel

```
//for staff ddl
public List<Staff> Staff { get; set;     
public int? SelectedStaffId { get; set; }
public IEnumerable<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem> StaffItems
{
    get { return new System.Web.Mvc.SelectList(Staff, "StaffID", "FirstName"); }
}//end
```

view

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedStaffId, Model.StaffItems, "--Who is taking appointment--", new { @class = "form-control", @id = "ddlValuer" })
```

Now I want to bind a variable number of dropdownlists. I expected to achieve this would be a simple loop as below: (BUT THIS DOESN'T WORK)

ViewModel

```
//for offerState ddl
public List<OfferState> OfferStates { get; set; }
public int? SelectedOfferStateId { get; set; }
public IEnumerable<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem> OfferStateItems
{
    get { return new System.Web.Mvc.SelectList(OfferStates, "OfferStateID", "Description"); }
}//end
```

View

```
for (var i = 0; i < Model.Offers.Count; i++)
{
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4">@Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.Offers[i].Offer1, null, new { @class = "form-control", @disabled = "disabled" })</div>
        <div class="col-lg-8">@Html.DropDownListFor(m => Model.Offers[i].OfferStateID, Model.OfferStateItems, "--State--", new { @class = "form-control" })</div>
    </div>
}
```

The items are never selected, --state-- (the default text), is always displayed. I have stepped through the code and can see there are three items with an OfferStateID.

Why is the default value always selected? Is there a better way?

Comment: try to use Html.ListBoxFor instead of Html.DropDownListFor http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12176735/getting-multiple-selected-values-in-html-dropdownlistfor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known limitation of using `DropDownListFor()` in a loop. You need to build a new `SelectList` in each iteration, or use an `EditorTemplate` and pass the `SelectList` to the template as `AdditionalViewData`

```
for (var i = 0; i < Model.Offers.Count; i++)
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Offers[i].OfferStateID, new SelectList(Model.OfferStateItems, "OfferStateID", "Description", Model.Offers[i].OfferStateID), "--State--", new { @class = "form-control" })
}
```

where `OfferStateItems` is `IEnumerable<OfferStates>` (not `SelectList`)

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I have tried it and my problem persists

Answer (score 0):

In your model just change this:

```
 public IEnumerable<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem> OfferStateItems
{
    get { return new System.Web.Mvc.SelectList(OfferStates, "OfferStateID",     "Description"); }
}//end
```

To this

```
public List<OfferStates> OfferStateItems{get;set;}
```

Then create a constructor for your ModelView

```
public yourViewModel()
{
      this.OfferStateItems=(place here the method to populate the list)
}
```

Then you can use that list with the items you need, and use a HTML helper to write the items.