Display Multi-select dropdown list in .NET 8
I'm new to .NET 8 and I've build a form using MVC, EF and X.PagedList. My form has a multi-select drop-down list. I'm able to save the form to database. The Multi-select drop-down list is saved to database like this ["abc", "xyz"].
Here is my model:
public partial class Bat
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    
    public string? FirstName { get; set; }
    public string? LastName { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string>? MyMultiSelectList { get; set; } = null!; 
}

But when I go to view the Index page, I get an error at the IQueryable line below:

ArgumentException: Expression of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable1[System.String]' cannot be used for parameter of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList1[System.String]' of method 'System.Collections.Generic.IList1[System.String] PopulateList[String](System.Collections.Generic.IList1[System.String], System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[System.String])' (Parameter 'arg0').

Here is my Index method code:
public IActionResult Index(int? page)
{
    IQueryable<Bat> Bats = _context.Bats.AsQueryable();

    int pageSize = 10;
    int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);

    return View(Bats.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
}

Here is the code of my Index page:
@using X.PagedList
@using X.PagedList.Mvc.Core
@model X.PagedList.IPagedList<QII.Models.Initiative>

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstName)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LastName)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.MyMultiSelectList)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MyMultiSelectList)
            </td>
            <td>
                <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Edit</a> |
                <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Details</a> |
                <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Delete</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
    </tbody>
</table>

If I change the
public IEnumerable<string>? MyMultiSelectList { get; set; } = null!;

to
public string? MyMultiSelectList { get; set; } = null!;

error goes away but only first selected option 'abc' is stored in database.
Can someone tell me how to display this multi-select drop-down list as string like abc,xyz on my Index page and get rid of this error?

check ListBoxfor https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12176735/getting-multiple-selected-values-in-html-dropdownlistfor

I checked the link above, do you mean to implement multi-select I need to create a new ViewModel?

Since the IEnumerable type cannot be directly bound to the view. If you want to display the value in the view, you can convert the IEnumerable to a string, create a viewmodel to contain the converted string value, and then in the controller's Index method, convert the Bat instance to a BatViewModel instance, and use the string.Join() method to convert the IEnumerable<string>  to a string, after that bind the BatViewModel in the view.The following is an example for your reference.
BatViewModel:
public class BatViewModel
{
     public Guid Id { get; set; }

       
     public string? FirstName { get; set; }
        
     public string? LastName { get; set; }

       
     public string? MyMultiSelectList { get; set; } 
 }

Controller:
public IActionResult Index(int? page)
{
     IQueryable<Bat> Bats = _context.Bats.AsQueryable();
     int pageSize = 10;
     int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);

     var batViewModels = Bats
  .Select(b => new BatViewModel
  {
      Id = b.Id,
      FirstName = b.FirstName,
      LastName = b.LastName,
      MyMultiSelectList = b.MyMultiSelectList != null ? string.Join(",", b.MyMultiSelectList) : string.Empty
  });

     var pagedList = batViewModels.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize);

     return View(pagedList);
}

View:
@model X.PagedList.IPagedList<BatViewModel>
@using X.PagedList.Mvc.Core

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstOrDefault().FirstName)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstOrDefault().LastName)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstOrDefault().MyMultiSelectList)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MyMultiSelectList)
            </td>
            <td>
                <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Edit</a> |
                <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Details</a> |
                <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Delete</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
    </tbody>
</table>

MyDbContext:
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Bat> Bats { get; set; }

        
}

Result:

And it should be noted that using DisplayNameFor here will cause an exception, which can be avoided by using FirstOrDefault().

Thank you for explaining why ViewModel is required.

You can try to convert the IEnumerable to a comma-separated string in your view:
public partial class Bat
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    
    public string? FirstName { get; set; }
    public string? LastName { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string>? MyMultiSelectList { get; set; } = null!; 

    // New property to get comma-separated string
    public string MyMultiSelectListAsString 
    {
        get
        {
            return MyMultiSelectList != null ? string.Join(", ", MyMultiSelectList) : string.Empty;
        }
    }
}

Update the view of the Index page:
@using X.PagedList
@using X.PagedList.Mvc.Core
@model X.PagedList.IPagedList<QII.Models.Initiative>

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstName)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LastName)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.MyMultiSelectListAsString)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MyMultiSelectListAsString)
            </td>
            <td>
                <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Edit</a> |
                <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Details</a> |
                <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Delete</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
    </tbody>
</table>


I tried what you suggested but same error.

Your view also seems to be declaring a model of type IPagedList<QII.Models.Initiative>, when your return View(Bats.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize)); line is delivering a PagedList<Bat>, which could also be the issue.
You might also want to clarify whether the error is specifically in the IQueryable line or after the return.
EDIT: If it applies to the IQueryable line, then read the following:
Your issue seems to stem from the fact that somewhere in that operation, an IList object is expected but the object present is IEnumerable.
It does not seem to be related to PagedList, but with your DbContext class, which could be present if you are new and using a code-first approach.
You should check if your DbContext class contains the appropriate type for the Bats property (in a normal database-first approach, it should be DbSet<Bat>).
If it already does, then presenting your DbContext class here would be helpful.

I can confirm that error is coming at line IQueryable Bats = _context.Bats.AsQueryable(); In my DbCOntext I have public virtual DbSet Bats { get; set; }

I'm working with an existing database.

@joegreen I guess your error could be related to the underlying database type and how the data is read, but this goes beyond what I can answer. The easiest way to get past your error would probably be changing IEnumerable? MyMultiSelectList to an IList?, as it is the expected type
